# Id Generation taking user id and Internal counter into account

Tags: mysql, primary-key, scalability

On my quest to find the best way to generate a numerical BigInt id for my MySQL primary key rows for some of my tables. I don't want to rely on the internal clock. I DO care about how the URL of my site will look like look and I don't want to put GUID in the URL.

What I was thinking is to use a GUID as the primary key, but use another column to query the data upon. That column will include the `User_Id (INT) + Counter (INT)`. The counter is for a specific user and after each insert I increase that counter by 1.

I want to have the following URL structure:

```
http://website.com/21474836470099
```

The 214748364700 part is the user id and the second part '99' is the counter.  Then I can substract that number and create a select query that query that unique id (non-primary key) column. I might use -99 at the end so I won't need to write the entire number as bigint so I know how to extract the '99' value from the string.

I care about scalability and having a numerical ID in the URL not GUID. And again, I don't want to rely on the server id or internal clock, just the information I have in the database. Furthermore, **I don't want the URL to be dependent on the primary key**.

Another option is to create a new column BOX_COUNT that will hold the total of number of boxes until that specific insertion.

ex:

```
ID = 1
BOX_NAME = "name 1"
COUTNER = 1

ID = 5
BOX_NAME = "box 5"
COUNTER = 5
```

I have a column of TOTAL_USER_BOXES that increment by 1 on each insert of a new BOX for a specific user. Each user box counter starts at 0 by default.

So I can select the box by:

```
SELECT FROM boxes 
WHERE user_id = 214748364700 AND counter = 5
```

That way the URL is not dependent on the primary key. It's like using GUID to make the rows independent on various shards, kind of. And **yet another option** is to use a user_id + counter as a primary key together and ditch the incremental BigInt AI primary key or GUID (maybe this ones seems the best, and it's scalable too!)

**Specific application consideration:** My idea is to de-normalize my tables anyway, so I won't need to make joins. Use it like NoSQL, so each box row will contain a column with the items and their properties as JSON Like. So when I want to insert a new item, I will have to deseralize and then serealize the data. Select + Modify + Insert instead of just Insert.

**Result:**

url like: `http://domain.com/93,22` or `http://domain.com/92-12`

Short URL for specific BOX with its ITEMS in my webpage, ids that are independent, not relying on any clock sync like uuid_shrot() or any other library and complicated stuff to make unique ids.

Hope to hear some suggestions and if you have a better ID I'm welcome to hear Thanks guys.

Comment: How will you know that you need to subtract the last n digits when in the future there happens to be so many records?

Comment: I will use '-' and use regex to get that part. ex. 214748364700-99 or ',': 214748364700,99. I can even use 214748364700/99 as part of the URL. This means that even if in the future I will have to use GUIDs as keys for some reason, I can migrate to it without inflecting the search engine crawling.

Comment: I want sequencial GUID, and for that I will have to use the clock. Another option is to use uuid_short() in MySQL. That a risk in clock sync issues, but I can catch the exception if their is an attempt to  put duplicate primaries. I might use Auto-increment, but I don't want to rely on it for my URLs

Comment: I might as well as create a secondary column that holds a the latest counter value for each box and items. So I can query the box by the user_id + that specific counter column